# Delegate or Lambda?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I just bought Xamarin student edition and reading in the starting tutorials.

I've found this code sample

a lambda expression as in the following example:

```
aButton.Click += (sender, e) => {
    aLabel.Text = "Hello from the button";
};
```

Instead, we could use a C# 2.0 anonymous method with the delegate syntax:

```
aButton.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    aLabel.Text = "Hello from the button";
};
```

The source is [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,_world)

My questions are

1. When or why should I use a delegate ( yes I did read C# documentation)
2. What is better in this case? a lambda or delegate?

To be clear: there is nothing wrong with the code I just can't find out why I should use the first or the second method.

Comment: There are a few cases (especially when interfacing with older .NET 2.0 methods) which require a `delegate` to be passed in and you can't simply write an in-line lambda. Beyond that, _generally_ lambdas are favoured now in the development community. As for your specific usage above, AFAIK there's no functional difference. (I actually might not be surprised if they compile to the same/similar IL)

Comment: Thank you @ChrisSinclair it's more clear now and also thanks for the answer martin mulder

Comment: Just as another note. Kind of related. Be careful not to register an anonymous method when you need to be able to unregister the event to avoid a leak. `aButton.Click -= (sender, e) => { ... }` is a different lambda than the one registered, so the other one will not get unregistered and will leak. To avoid this create a named method. It is not much more difficult to create one `aButton.Click += OnClick`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference!

Anonymous methods came with C#2.0. 
Labmda came with C#3.0.

Labmda is just a shorter form to create an anonymous method (or an expression tree depending on the context).